# Extract complete URL from href using Python

Tags: python, web-crawler, urllib

I am doing a project on web crawling for which I need to find all links within a given web page. Till now I was using `urljoin` in `urllib.parse`. But now I found that some links are not properly joined using the `urljoin` function.

For e.g. the `<a>` tag might be something like `<a href="a.xml?value=basketball">A</a>`. The complete address however might be `http://www.example.org/main/test/a.xml?value=basketball`, but the `urljoin` function will give wrong results ( something like `http://www.example.com/a.xml?value=basketball`).

Code which I am using:

```
parentUrl = urlQueue.get()

html = get_page_source(parentUrl)

bSoup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
aTags = bSoup.find_all('a', href=True)

for aTag in aTags:
    childUrl = aTag.get('href')

    # just to check if the url is complete or not(for .com only)
    if '.com' not in childUrl:
        # this urljoin is giving invalid resultsas mentioned above
        childUrl = urljoin(parentUrl, childUrl)
```

Is there any way through which I can correctly join two URLs, including these cases ?

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you provide minimal working code to build on.

Comment: Tell me if you need something else... However my main concern is to make absolute link address using href attribute, which sometimes may not contain the complete path.

Comment: Delete the NOTE. It is a browser feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some tweaks to get this working. In your case pass base URI with trailing slash. Everything you will need to accomplish this is written in the [docs of urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://www.example.org/main/test','a.xml?value=basketball')
'http://www.example.org/main/a.xml?value=basketball'
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://www.example.org/main/test/','a.xml?value=basketball')
'http://www.example.org/main/test/a.xml?value=basketball'
```

BTW: this is a perfect use case to factor out the code for building URLs into a separate function. Then write some unit tests to verify its working as expected and even works with your edge cases. Afterwards use it in your web crawler code.

Comment: This code works for Python 2.7 but can be applied to Python 3.5 if you use urllib.parse as the OP mentioned.

Comment: Thank you sir. It seems to work on some cases I tried. Let me test it completely before accepting this answer.